# Accessing the second half of a string in a pythonic way

Tags: python

I have a set of strings of variable length. They all have identical characters at the start and different characters at the end.

```py
a1="I went to the shop"
a2="I went to the wishing well"
```

I want to access the varying characters at the end. The most intuitive way of doing this is

```py
a1[14:-1]
```

which gives the string "sho".

I could get the whole word by doing

```py
a1[14:len(a1)]
```

however this doesn't feel very pythonic.

What is the pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: BTW, you can use `a1[14:]`... is this pythonic enough?

Comment: thanks, I'm new to python - that looks great!

Comment: Cool, glad I could help :)

Comment: Or more general: `a1[len(a1)/2:]` if you want.